# Inherited xpath not showing - Odoo v8

Tags: python, xpath, odoo, odoo-8

I'm inheriting the view `mrp_workorder_variation.mrp_production_workcenter_form_view_inherit_2` and adding a new page, but it's not shown, I don't know why, this is my code:

```
  <record id="mrp_production_workcenter_form_view_inherit_3" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">MRP Production Work Book Block</field>
        <field name="model">book.block.code</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp_workorder_variation.mrp_production_workcenter_form_view_inherit_2"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <xpath expr="//page[@string='Input/Output Products']" position="after">
                <page string="Book Block">                                                         
                    <group>                                                                         
                        <group string="Book Block">                                               
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="description"/>
                        </group>                                                                    
                    </group>                                                   
                </page>  
            </xpath>

        </field>
    </record>
```

This is the original view I'm inheriting:

```
 <record id="mrp_production_workcenter_form_view_inherit_2" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">MRP Production Workcenter Line</field>
        <field name="model">mrp.production.workcenter.line</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp_operations.mrp_production_workcenter_form_view_inherit"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <xpath expr="//page[@string='Information']" position="after">
                <page string="Input/Output Products">                                                         
                    <group>                                                                         
                        <group string="Input Products">                                               
                            <field name="mrp_workorder_variation_line_ids" nolabel="1"
                                attrs="{'readonly': [('state','!=','draft')]}">
                                <tree string="Input Product" editable="bottom">
                                    <field name="product_id"  
                                        on_change="on_change_product_uom(product_id)"/>
                                    <field name="product_uom"/>
                                    <field name="product_qty"/>                                        
                                </tree>
                                <form string="Input Product" version="7.0">
                                    <field name="product_id"/>                                        
                                    <field name="product_uom"/>                                        
                                    <field name="product_qty"/>                                        
                                </form>
                            </field>
                        </group>                                                                    
                    </group>                                                                        
                    <group>                                                                         
                        <group string="Output Products">                                               
                            <field name="mrp_workorder_variation_output_line_ids" nolabel="1"
                                 attrs="{'readonly': [('state','!=','startworking')]}">
                                <tree string="Output Product" editable="bottom">
                                    <field name="product_id" 
                                        on_change="on_change_product_uom(product_id)"/>
                                    <field name="product_uom"/>
                                    <field name="product_qty"/>                                        
                                </tree>
                                <form string="Output Product" version="7.0">
                                    <field name="product_id" />                                        
                                    <field name="product_uom"/>                                        
                                    <field name="product_qty"/>                                        
                                </form>
                            </field>
                        </group>                                                                    
                    </group>                                                                        

                </page>  
            </xpath>

        </field>
    </record>
```

ANy ideas on why this is happening?

I also tried inheriting the original `<xpath expr="//page[@string='Information']"` but same result, no new page is shown.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

If I change it to this:

```
`<record id="mrp_production_workcenter_form_view_inherit_3" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">MRP Production Work Book Block</field>
        <field name="model">book.block.code</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp_operations.mrp_production_workcenter_form_view_inherit"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <xpath expr="//page[@string='Information']" position="after">
                <page string="Book Block">                                                         
                    <group>                                                                         
                        <group string="Book Block">                                               
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="description"/>
                        </group>                                                                    
                    </group>                                               
                </page>  
            </xpath>

        </field>
    </record>`
```

Which is the original module, still no new page is shown

Comment: In which module the original view is? In mrp??

Comment: Hi, it's in 'mrp_operations'

Comment: Then ref="mrp_operations.view_id_of _original_view_you_want_to_inherit"

Comment: I know, but it's the same result, no new page is shown

Comment: It is very weird, I don't get it

Comment: make sure you have registered your view file in openerp manifest file.

Comment: Hi Odedra, yes it is, I've noticed this on the original view "<field name="inherit_id" eval="False"/>" I don't think it's because of this, but you never know

Comment: Can you add this code in xpath -- > `<xpath expr="//sheet/notbook/page[@string='Information']" position="after"`

Comment: Hi, Added the code, still nothing :(, I don't get it

Comment: Without keeping same model for inherited views, how will you proceed?

Comment: Why are the models different? Is your model `book.block.code` inheriting from model `mrp.production.workcenter.line`?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you are allowed to select a page by string attribute. Not sure why. I think you can use a named page.

Try selecting on the page number //page[first()] or //page[last()] and I am pretty sure you can select on a nth page as well.

You can also try overwriting their view entirely and just include your page in the xpath they are already using. In this case essentially copy their view entirely and namespace the xml id.

```
 <record id="addon_namespacehere.mrp_production_workcenter_form_view_inherit_2" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">MRP Production Workcenter Line</field>
    <field name="model">mrp.production.workcenter.line</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp_operations.mrp_production_workcenter_form_view_inherit"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <xpath expr="//page[@string='Information']" position="after">
            <page string="Input/Output Products">                                                         
                <group>                                                                         
                    <group string="Input Products">                                               
                        <field name="mrp_workorder_variation_line_ids" nolabel="1"
                            attrs="{'readonly': [('state','!=','draft')]}">
                            <tree string="Input Product" editable="bottom">
                                <field name="product_id"  
                                    on_change="on_change_product_uom(product_id)"/>
                                <field name="product_uom"/>
                                <field name="product_qty"/>                                        
                            </tree>
                            <form string="Input Product" version="7.0">
                                <field name="product_id"/>                                        
                                <field name="product_uom"/>                                        
                                <field name="product_qty"/>                                        
                            </form>
                        </field>
                    </group>                                                                    
                </group>                                                                        
                <group>                                                                         
                    <group string="Output Products">                                               
                        <field name="mrp_workorder_variation_output_line_ids" nolabel="1"
                             attrs="{'readonly': [('state','!=','startworking')]}">
                            <tree string="Output Product" editable="bottom">
                                <field name="product_id" 
                                    on_change="on_change_product_uom(product_id)"/>
                                <field name="product_uom"/>
                                <field name="product_qty"/>                                        
                            </tree>
                            <form string="Output Product" version="7.0">
                                <field name="product_id" />                                        
                                <field name="product_uom"/>                                        
                                <field name="product_qty"/>                                        
                            </form>
                        </field>
                    </group>                                                                    
                </group>                                                                        

            </page> 
           <page string="Book Block">                                                         
                <group>                                                                         
                    <group string="Book Block">                                               
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="description"/>
                    </group>                                                                    
                </group>                                                   
            </page>   
        </xpath>

    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Hi, but I don't think this can be usable, because I have like 6 other custom modules which should inherit this view, I don't know how can I do this with everyone, also, where can I find the page number if it doesn't exist?

Comment: No, it is not really a good idea to edit the original view. However you can can create a view and actually use the same xml_id used in the original view. So if the original view id was `addon_name.view_id` your can call your view `addon_name.view_id` and your view will be used rather than the original. Then you wont have to use xpath to inject your content.

Comment: Sure I understand, but the model is different, book_block_code is another model, so it will not load these fields, unless I call it with the same _name, right? And for the other modules I don't understand how can I achieve this though, going to try now